# Unable to Ping from Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, ping

I have a LAN setup 192.168.1.0/24, unusually I have 3 devices on the network that I am unable to ping from my Linux box, but can from a windows laptop on the same network. The Linux box however can ping other devices on the network...

IP configuration, server is a static IP 192.168.1.198 and this is a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 ufw is off.

[IP Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPz3y.png)

From my Linux box I can ping another Ubuntu box, and many other devices on the network without issue

[ping ubuntu server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0NsJ.png)

From my linux box, I cannot ping the device at 192.168.1.222 I get Destination host unreachable
[ping 192.168.1.222 Destination host unreachable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pP0O.png)

I get the same from 2 other devices 192.168.1.10, and 192.168.1.20

pinging the same device from my Windows laptop on the same network gives a response without issue
[Pinging from windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mu2W.png)

running tcpdump on a separate ssh connection I can see ping request to devices that work captured but noting to the address that doesn't work

[tcpdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVv0A.png)

I have racked my brain for days on this, and just cannot work out why the packets to these devices are not being routed out of the linux box. I even tried it from another linux box and got exactly the same issue. so it is not down to the install of this one box.

Update results of arp-scan show the devices present on the network

[arp-scan results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDSbe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I see a problem in your settings and consequently an obvious error in network communication.

### Situation

You have two IP addresses **on the same network** in the enp8s0 interface settings. One (primary) is 192.168.1.197 (OK) and one (secondary) is 192.168.1.198 (wrong). There can be multiple addresses, but not from the same subnet. Secondary address is **dynamic**, this means that it is probably assigned using a DHCP server.

Your Linux box server will use an incorrect address for some connections.

Look at the your screenshot at the link [ping 192.168.1.222 Destination host unreachable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pP0O.png). It can be seen there that the ICMP message about the unavailability of the target with the address 192.168.1.122 comes from the address 192.168.1.197.

```
From 192.168.1.197 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Such a response usually comes from another remote network node that could no longer provide a connection to the destination. If the node with the error is the Linux box itself, it is a local problem directly in it.

### Recommended solution

**Delete the second address**, and then include the command responses here for next analysis:

```
ip addr
ip route
ip neigh
```

Comment: I only see/saw 192.168.1.197 not 192.168.1.177. So I was assuming it was trying via the same pathway as the others. Regardless, yes I had missed the point you make and agree.

Comment: I mistook the IP address, it should have been 192.168.1.197 instead of 192.168.1.77. I'm sorry. I've already fixed it.